# Am I correctly understanding this recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

Could someone please help walk me through my recursive code?  Here's how I make sense of it (but I do not think I am stepping through the code correctly):

1. `if ( first > last ) return -1`
2. else
3. `if ( result == 0 ) return last`
4. `else return SeqSearch (data, first, last-1, key)`
5. restart the method but with `last` as `last-1` ("keller")
6. repeat steps 1, 2, and 3
7. `else return SeqSearch(data, first, last-1, key)`
8. restart the method but with `last` as `last-1` ("six")
9. etc ...

Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String[] data = new String[]{"help","jackson","six","keller","mean"};
    int first = 0;
    int last = data.length-1;
    String key ="help";
    System.out.println(SeqSearch(data,first,last,key));
}
public static int SeqSearch(String[] data,int first,int last,String key)
{
    if(first > last)
        return -1;
    else{
        int result = data[last].compareTo(key);
        if(result == 0)
            return last;
        else
            return SeqSearch(data,first,last-1,key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are basically searching the array of strings starting with the last one. If that's not the key, repeat the search, but remove the last string from the array and try again. If you end up with a 1 string array (`first == last` is true) and that string is not the key, search again. But in that case `first > last` is true, and the key was not found. I don't think recursion provides anything useful to this problem, which could be much better resolved iteratively, but I guess you are just using it as an experiment to understand recursion.

Comment: Yeah, just for trying to understand. So when I check last and it is not the key. I removed it completely from the array? so the array just keeps getting smaller and smaller?

Comment: Well, you are not actually removing it from the array. You are just limiting the portion of the array under consideration by passing `last - 1` to your recursive call. Hopefully that makes sense. "Removing from the array" was not a correct way of expressing what's happening.

Comment: The array itself stays the same, to reiterate.

Comment: I hope this is homework, because recursion is an *awful* way to do this...this is the simplest of loops.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker In Java, perhaps; but some languages lend themselves to the recursive version: this can be expressed very simply in Haskell, e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to understand a recursive function is to break it down into its *base* cases and *recursive* cases.

This `SeqSearch` has two base cases:

#### 1. Not found

```
if (first > last)
    return -1;
```

#### 2. Value found

```
if (data[last].compareTo(key) == 0)
    return last;
```

Now, that leaves the recursive cases. Here, we have only one recursive case, but there could be several.

Now, when designing a recursive function, you have to ensure that each recursive call is *reduced*, or *simpler*, than previous calls, in the sense that we're getting closer to one of the base cases each time. This is very much related to the mathematical concept of [Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

So, each call to the recursive case must progress one "step" closer to the answer.<sup>*</sup>  Here we see that the value of `last` is reduced by subtracting one, bringing it closer to zero at each step.

In turn, this means that the function is referring to a smaller and smaller subset of the `data` array; conceptually, this is analogous to passing a smaller array to the recursive call, which has one less element.

At this point, the base cases start to make sense:

1. When `first` is greater than `last`, we have an array with no elements: the *tail* of the list has overtaken its *head*.
2. When the search key is found, we return its index as our result.

This function is peculiar (among search functions), in that it finds the first matching index from the **end** of the list; a more commonplace operation is to find the first matching index from the **beginning** of a list.

This could be achieved by incrementing `first` instead of decrementing `last`. This would still count as a reduction --- even though it is adding --- because the recursive step is strictly smaller than the original step.

---

<sup>*</sup> This means that each recursive call much be "simpler" than the previous one; so if you can understand the problem at any point, the next step should be simpler; the only complication is that it is nested within the original step.